# Nvidia low graphics mode

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, intel-graphics, nvidia-prime

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on a Asus A53SV with Nvidia 540M and Intel Sandy Bridge i7. I've installed nvidia-331 proprietary driver and also the Intel graphics official driver.

After the last graphics update, when I switch to nvidia trough prime, the low graphics mode screen appears, and then I have to switch back to intel manually.

I've purged and installed again all nvidia packages, and the issue still remains. Is there a way to fix this? maybe a rollback of the update.

**08/14/2014 Update:** I tried to purge all nvidia package (removing them), rebooting, and them re-install them again, then reboot again. Did not work!.

**Note:** I think the cause of this problem rely on intel-graphics. Maybe nvidia-prime doesn't know the existing of this new intel driver.

**08/15/2014 Update** I stumble upon [this page](https://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/04/how-to-add-intel-linux-graphics-driver-repository-in-ubuntu/) than showed me how to remove the intel graphics driver

```
    sudo apt-get purge intel-linux-graphics-installer && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then I rebooted, and nothing...

So I'll just re-install Ubuntu when I have the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to re-install Ubuntu, so I close my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading should work. Check the "history" tab in the software center and downgrade all the intel changes from 1.0.5 -> 1.0.6.

As far as I can tell, there are two possible causes:

1. The intel update installs a package called i915-3.15-3.13-dkms, which I guess is a backport of the Intel graphics kernel module in 3.15 to the ubuntu 3.13 kernel. This might be incompatible with the Nvidia kernel module.
2. A bug in the intel driver.

Comment: It seems that I can't downgrade intel graphics package. I've tried with Synaptic and apt-get install intel-linux-graphics-installer=1.0.5-0intel1, neither of them let me do it. The command apt-cache showpkg intel-linux-graphics-installer showed me none "Reverse Provides:"